# ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘ks’

Tags: r, installation, cran

I am trying to install the R library **rugarch**

1) I installed R and Rstudio

```
R version: 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
```

2) I entered in Rstudio **install.packages("rugarch")**. But received messages:

> ERROR: dependency ‘mvtnorm’ is not available for package ‘ks’
>   * removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ks’
>
> ERROR: dependency ‘ks’ is not available for package ‘rugarch’
>   * removing ‘/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rugarch’
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘rugarch’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘/tmp/RtmpsVPt7o/downloaded_packages’

3) Also tried  "Tools" --> "Install packages" --> rugarch, but result is the same

What should I do to install **rugarch**?

Comment: Can you install a more recent `R version`

Comment: @akrun what number of version?

Comment: You can check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/) and select the one based on your OS

Comment: @akrun but in rugarch documentation i have found "Depends R (>= 3.0.2), methods, parallel". And it seems that my version is OK

Comment: ok, sounds good then

Comment: try `install.packages("rugarch", dependencies = T)`

Comment: Just a heads up, I was able to install `rugarch` in my `Ubuntu 19` with R version 3.5.2 using `install.packages("rugarch", dependencies = T)`

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan thank you, but install.packages("rugarch", dependencies = T) did not help(

Comment: Then I guess you need to upgrade R to at least 3.5.2 if you want this package to be installed.